# Finding a certain set of numbers in egrep

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep

I am currently stuck on trying to solve this issue I am having. I am trying to use egrep to find either 5 digit consecutive numbers or 9 digit consecutive numbers.

Right now I am getting only the 5 digit number that appears on one line and nothing else after that. I currently have...

```
egrep '^[[:digit:]]{5} | [[:digit:]]{9}$' file.txt
```

For example if my file.txt had

```
123456789 24
12345 642
94363
```

What will be found is

**12345** 642

How can I make it so that it will check every line and see the other 5 and 9 digit numbers?

**Edit:Using parentheses around the expression finds...**

1234**56789** 4

**12345** 642

Comment: Remove $ from your expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
egrep '^[[:digit:]]{5} | [[:digit:]]{9}$' file.txt
```

remove space after `^[[:digit:]]{5}`, the 3th line no space after 5 digit, so can't match.

remove space before `[[:digit:]]{9}`, the first line no space before 123456789,  so can't match it.

Comment: Oh my, thank you. I didn't know that a random space becomes part of your regular expression. This fixed my problem, thank you.

Comment: Also, remove the `$` as in that data there is no line ending in 9 digits. In fact, remove the whole latter part as the former will match all three lines (test it with `egrep -o ...`).

Comment: @JamesBrown, you right, even after remove space, and the $,  it's not a correct regex pattern. will match such as  123456 12 too.

Comment: ... but as long as op is happy. :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `()` around the expression:

```
$ egrep "(^| )([[:digit:]]{5}|[[:digit:]]{9})( |$)" file
123456789 24
12345 642
94363
```

Add `^` and `$` if needed.

**Edit:** If you add `-o` to the `egrep` you see what you get:

```
$ egrep -o "(^| )([[:digit:]]{5}|[[:digit:]]{9})( |$)" file
123456789 
12345 
94363
```

Comment: I tried this before, but counts the last 5 digits of the first line and then the 5 digits on the second then stops.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I edited my post to show you what I meant, sorry for the confusion.